# Not getting "Platform Connect : OData 2.0" as connection type in setting up external source

Tags: lightning-connect

I only see Simple URL as options for Type. Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Yes, I experienced this too. Would be great to get some insight.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that OData is only available to connect with via Lightning Connect which isn't generally available yet. Until then you can only test it in a dev sandbox.

We anticipate this product will be generally available in the November 2014 to January 2015 time frame. Any unreleased services or features referenced in this or other public statements are not currently available and may not be delivered on time or at all. Customers who purchase Salesforce applications should make their purchase decisions based upon features that are currently available.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=platform_connect_about.htm&language=en_US